# MongoDB - Reading an Integer

Tags: mongodb, integer

I'm using Mongo as my database, and I'm having trouble reading in an integer. More specifically, an embedded integer. Here's how my database entry looks: https://gyazo.com/5de8a61e02b79c00a5bd9c7e7b05c009

And here's how I'm trying to read in the information: https://gyazo.com/983f786362e038247d927704a6ead0b4

It's throwing the error "NullPointerException" at the "document.getInteger("custom.first.one")" line. However, as you can see, I have that path set up correctly in my database.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have a float in your database. Convert your floats in to integers and this should work!

Thats how you can insert ints in to the database native!

```
db.data.update({'name': 'zero'}, {'$set': {'value': NumberInt(0)}})
```

Comment: Hm, alrighty! It was hard to find an example of getting an integer out of the Document object, so I'll certainly give this a try!

Comment: I just tried using this and it didn't throw an error when writing the update. However, when I look back into the database, a float value still shows: 0.0. The update output said the following: WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 }). So it found the document, however it didn't update it for some reason. And just to be sure, here's the last half of the update command I used: "{$set: {"custom.first.one":NumberInt(0)}}". Any thoughts?

Comment: And the method I showed in my first post works on top level fields. I don't have to convert those to integers when inserting them into the database. It's just the embedded fields. Sorry for my multiple comments, I'm just trying to learn! haha.